# css parser and selector in NodeJS

Tags: css, node.js

I'm looking for a similar lib than this : https://github.com/alexdunae/css_parser for NodeJS.

All I know is this : https://github.com/visionmedia/css

But it doesn't do everything I need.

For instance, if I parse :

```
.behavior1 {color: red}
.behavior2 {background-color: black}
```

And I give this to the find function : '.behavior1.behavior2', I get this JSON :

```
{"color": "red", "background-color": "black"}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/visionmedia/rework might work for you

here's some characters to get to the minimum required by stackoverflow.

Comment: rework seems to helps news stylesheet engines like stylus to add prefix, manages other media queries ... I don't think it can answer to my problem.